# C# precision calculations multiplying int and double

Tags: c#, .net, int, double, multiplication

Consider this code:

```
Console.WriteLine((197688 * 0.1) == 19768.800000000003); // True
Console.WriteLine((197688 * 0.1) == 19768.8); // False
```

is an incorrect calculation?

Java-> http://ideone.com/D3QsUo
C# -> http://ideone.com/wp5pM9

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Been discussed a lot of times; floating-point is not perfect, you need to compare with a delta.

Comment: I never claimed to be a computer scientist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floating-point types (and calculations) are imprecise in *nature*. They work in binary, not in decimal, and hence calculations yield “unexpected” decimal values.

Compare it with this:

```
Console.WriteLine((197688 * 0.1m) == 19768.800000000003m); // False
Console.WriteLine((197688 * 0.1m) == 19768.8m); // True
```

The result is as you'd expect, because `decimal` is used. As the name suggests, it's suited for decimal calculations because of its internal representation.

Side note: The rule of thumb is ***never*** use floating-point types for monetary calculations. Exactly becuase of precision issues with decical values.

Comment: Also another rule of thumb is to never use `==` with floating point types to keep from falling in to the same issue too.

Answer (score 0):

A `double` only has 15-16 digits of precision - the compiler will translate your literal to the  closest value that can be represented by a `double` which is this case is `19768.8`